# element class doesn't load its CSS property after being added to iframe via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to add some elements using jQuery to an iframe after I load it.

$('#container').html(''). The added element appears on the page but the class doesn't load the css property! Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

This is the class

.player{width: 150px;   height: 30px;background-image: url(../img/bg.svg);background-repeat: no-repeat; padding: 5px;}

This is how it shows 
[image]

this is how it is supposed to be

[image]

Comment: I think I have to add that this issue happens in an Iframe inside an AngularJS directive!

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the right CSS?
Have you tried changing the class name then applying the CSS to it?
Have you tried changing the CSS like this:

```
`iframe {
width: 150px;
height: 30px;
background-image: url(../img/bg.svg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 5px;
}`
```

?

Try placing the iframe without a class inside a div and then calling it in your CSS file.

```
`<div class="iframewrap">
    <iframe></iframe>
 </div>

    .iframewrap iframe {
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url(../img/bg.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 5px;
    }`
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help!